# winforms chart, change values on x axis

Tags: winforms, charts

I have added values on x axis between 0-255. I add the values to a serie with serie.addXY(127,10000); When the chart is displayed, the values it shows on the x axis are -1, 49, 99...

How can I change this to display 0, 50,100?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting axis bounds. You can do that in the designer or via code:

```
        Chart1.ChartAreas["Default"].AxisX.Minimum = 0;
        Chart1.ChartAreas["Default"].AxisX.Maximum = 255;
```